# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, any>'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get some data from **mongodb**, and keep getting this error:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'

//app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {CommonService} from './common.service';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private newService: CommonService) {
    }

    Repdata;
    valbutton = "Save";

    ngOnInit() {
        this.newService.GetProcesses().subscribe(data => this.Repdata = data);
    }
}
```

//common.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    GetProcesses(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/getProcesses/')
                   .pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json())),
            catchError(error => Observable.of(null))

    }
}
```

Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'

Comment: What verson of Angular and RXJS are you using?

Comment: you are missing this  ')' to close your pipe

Comment: @GerardoJaramillo Asks an important question.`HttpModule` and `Http` hasn't been used since Angular 2.x, instead you would use `HttpClientModule` and `HttpClient` with Angular 4.x+. With RxJS 5+ you really don't need static imports like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';` anymore, you can just named imports like `import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, I'm using angular 2.4.1 and rxjs 6.5.2 at the moment, should I upgrade to a newer version of angular?

Comment: Depends on how complex your app is and if you have time to check everything, if you ask me you should. but if you have doubts please visit this page https://update.angular.io/#2.1:8.0.

Comment: after updating to angular 8 and rxjs 6, I updated my GetProcesses() function by removing the .json() from the response.json() and everything works now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a misplaced parenthesis in your `common.service.ts` file.

I made this code snippet for you to try it out, hope it does what you need

// common.service.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {catchError, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    GetProcesses() {
        let url = 'http://localhost:4000/getProcesses/';
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(
            map((response: Response) => response.json()),
            catchError(error => Observable.of(null))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work having `subscribe()` in `GetProcesses()`. Returning something from within a `subscribe()` will not return anything. It's not like `.then(response => response.json())` on a promise where that return or implicit returns passes it forward to other `.then()` statements. That is why `pipe()` was needed to process data and pass that processed data forward to the component/directive/etc consuming the service and doing `subscribe()`, in this case `AppComponent`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, usually I just subscribe to the api within the service and assign the returned output from the service's method to a variable within the component's scope. I missed his `.subscribe()` inside the component.
I guess his only problem was the parentheses.

Comment: Not good.
if you try to subscribe to GetProcess() you need to make it asObservable()
that why pipe() gonna help you

Comment: Thanks @Talg123, but it had been already clarified by Alexander. I updated my answer to avoid further confusion.