# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Response, {}>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im aware that this has been asked multiple times before, however, I could not figure out how to change my own code using following posts.

[Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Response, Recipe[]>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398107/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type-operatorfunctionresponse-recipe)

[Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Product[], ParamMap>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143477/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type-operatorfunctionproduct-paramma)

[Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, any>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813626/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type-operatorfunctionunknown-any)

---

**rest-api.service.ts**

```
specificObjectRequest(ids: string[]): Observable<any> {
  var idString = ids.join(); 
  const url = `${ApiServerUrl}/media_objects?ID=${idString}`;
  console.log("requesting from url: " + url);
  this.http.get(url, {}, {})
    .then(res => this.extractData = res.data)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  return;
}

tagRequest(topic: string){
    var url = `${ApiServerUrl}/tags?topic=${topic}`;
    url = encodeURI(url);
    console.log("requesting from url: " + url);
    this.http.get(url, {}, {})
      .then(res => this.extractData = res.data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    return map(this.extractData);
  }
```

I created this request using the official documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http and this tutorial

**filter.page.ts**

```
async requestMapTags(topic: string){
    await this.api.tagRequest(topic).subscribe(res => {  //Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Response, {}>'
      console.log(res);
      this.tagsRequestAnswer = res; 
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/filter/filter.page.ts(89,35): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<Response, {}>'.
```

From what I have read, it's a conflict between Promises and rxjs.

**Question:**
What do I need to change to get this working? Is there a way to add the required 'pipe' function in my code in order for it to work?

Comment: Where is tagRequest function ? Also why you only use only return in specificObjectRequest ?

Comment: I added the tagRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using promises here seems unnecessary, you can do it without more easily

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

tagRequest(topic: string){
    var url = `${ApiServerUrl}/tags?topic=${topic}`;
    url = encodeURI(url);
    return of(this.http.get(url, {}, {})).pipe(map(res => res.data));
  }

requestMapTags(topic: string){
    this.api.tagRequest(topic).subscribe(res => { 
      console.log(res);
      this.tagsRequestAnswer = res; 
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there no need to add the async in front of the requestMapTags?

Comment: no there is no need as you don't use Promises here, because async/await is only for Promises

Comment: Your code worked, the only problem is that Im getting is that res is a string, but I want it to be in a json format, is there any way I can parse it in the code? (Thanks anyways :))

Comment: what you mean saying string, is there object inside string ? or is it just string value ?, and what `res` do you mean?, `res` inside `tagRequest` or `requestMapTags` ?, actually backend should send it in correct format

Comment: the backend sends it in the correct "json" format, for some reason, res is in a string format when it arrives a the needed function, I solved the problem for now by adding JSON.parse(res)

Answer (score 1):

Your `tagRequest()` need to have a return value as an `Observable`  not `OperatorFunction<Response, {}>` ;

So try something like this :

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

tagRequest(topic: string){
    var url = `${ApiServerUrl}/tags?topic=${topic}`;
    url = encodeURI(url);
    console.log("requesting from url: " + url);
    return from(this.http.get(url, {}, {}));
  }
```

Comment: I used a combination of your code and Artyom Amiryans code and it worked, thank you! Same question here, is there any way I can parse the response into a json? Since im getting a res in a string format

Comment: Sure you can use `res.json()` to get JSON version